# Криптография на Python'е

Tags: python

Есть такой код по криптографии. Что он, собственно, делает? Может кто написать комментарии к нему, и описать сам принцип работы этого кода? Заранее спасибо.

```
import os
import random

#Путь
def Path():
    return 'C:\\'

def get_prime_numbers(n):
    a = [x for x in range (n+1)] #Создаем список размером n
    a[1] = 0
    prime_numbers = [] #Создаем второй список
    i = 2
    while (i <= n):
        if (a[i] != 0):
            prime_numbers.append(a[i]) #Заполняем второй список
            for j in range(i,n+1,i): #range(старт, стоп, шаг)
                a[j] = 0
        i += 1
    return prime_numbers #Возвращаем список

def get_d(e,fi_n):
    for i in range (2,fi_n):
        if ((e * i % fi_n) == 1):
            return i
            break;

def get_e(fi_n,prime_numbers):
    #enumerate() позволяет перебирать коллекцию элементов, отслеживая индекс текущего элемента
    for i,prnum in enumerate(prime_numbers):
        if ((fi_n % prnum) != 0):
            return prnum, i
            break;

def get_k(fi_n,prime_numbers):
    for j in prime_numbers:
        if((fi_n % j) != 0):
            return j
            break;

prime_numbers = get_prime_numbers(5000)
p = prime_numbers[47]
q = prime_numbers[56]
secret_path = os.path.join(Path(), 'secret.txt') #Соединяет пути с учётом особенностей операционной системы
n = p*q
fi_n = (p-1)*(q-1)
e,j = get_e(fi_n,prime_numbers)
d = get_d(e,fi_n)
secret_file = open(secret_path,'rb')
x = secret_file.read()
k = get_k(fi_n, prime_numbers[j+1:])
#print(x)
x1 = int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big')
#print(x1)
y = pow(pow(k,e,fi_n)*x1,1,fi_n)
print('A -> B: y = {0}'.format(y))
z = pow(y,d,fi_n)
print('B -> A: z = {0}'.format(z))
k_1 = get_d(pow(k, e*d,fi_n),fi_n)
S = pow(z*k_1,1, fi_n)
print('A: S(fromB) = {0}'.format(S))
S1 = pow(x1,d,fi_n)
print('A: S(check) = {0}'.format(S1))


print('e  = {0}'.format(e))
print('d  = {0}'.format(d))
print('k  = {0}'.format(k))
print('x  = {0}'.format(x1))
print('fi_n  = {0}'.format(fi_n))
print('k_1  = {0}'.format(k_1))
```

Comment: лучше попробуйте разобраться, с чем не справитесь оформите небольшими вопросами - будет большая вероятность, что вам помогут, а то так просто "стена"

Comment: Здесь не сервис по бесплатному разбору чужого кода :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код как я понял на первый взгляд с начало генерирует RSA ключи. Потом используя их что-то шифрует(вроде файл) Вот [алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)